# Execution timing with context manager

Tags: python, timing, execution-time, contextmanager, timeit

I was looking for a solution for timing code execution.
Of course, I found all sorts of solutions mostly suggesting the use of `timeit` module - which is pretty cool - or just using the `time` module. Neither of those really provides what I'm after.

I wanted a simple solution that

- I can quickly add to the code without changing the structure or logic
- can cover a single line or code block
- elegant and clean enough to even leave it in

I think I finally figured it out - using the context manager's dunder methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

The idea is we capture the time when the context manager starts (`__enter__`), then just let the code run in the context-manager-block, finally, we capture the time when the context manager ends (`__exit__`) and do something with the result (print and/or return).

So here's the snippet:

```py
import time


class ExecutionTimer:

    def __init__(self, message='Execution time', unit='s'):
        self.message = message
        self.unit = unit
        self.start_time = None
        self.end_time = None
        self.result = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.end_time = time.time()
        self.result = self.end_time - self.start_time
        self.print_time()

    def print_time(self):
        elapsed_time = self.result
        if self.unit == 'ms':
            elapsed_time *= 1000  # convert to milliseconds
        elif self.unit == 'us':
            elapsed_time *= 1e6  # convert to microseconds
        elif self.unit == 'ns':
            elapsed_time *= 1e9  # convert to nanoseconds

        print(f"{self.message}: {elapsed_time}{self.unit}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(1)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Execution (s): {end_time - start_time}s")

    with ExecutionTimer(message='Execution (s)', unit='s'):
        time.sleep(1)

    with ExecutionTimer(message="Execution (ms)", unit='ms'):
        time.sleep(1)

    with ExecutionTimer(message="Execution (us)", unit='us'):
        time.sleep(1)

    with ExecutionTimer(message="Execution (ns)", unit='ns'):
        time.sleep(1)

    # or just capture the value
    with ExecutionTimer(message="Execution (ns)", unit='ns') as my_timer:
        time.sleep(1)

    # notice we are not in the context manager any more
    print(my_timer.result)
    print(my_timer.result)
```

and its output:

```
Execution (s): 1.0000789165496826s
Execution (s): 1.0000693798065186s
Execution (ms): 1000.067949295044ms
Execution (us): 1000072.0024108887us
Execution (ns): 1000071287.1551514ns
Execution (ns): 1000077962.8753662ns
1.0000779628753662
1.0000779628753662

Process finished with exit code 0
```

There's definitely some room for improvement. It can be integrated with logging to only emit messages to a certain log level OR it could use a "dry run" parameter to control the execution print method. Etc.

Feel free to use, test, and modify it as you please. It would be awesome if you could leave your **constructive** comments, ideas, and improvements so we can all learn from them.

Cheers!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you want feedback on working code you should post on [codereview.se].

Comment: Note: It is allowed and encouraged to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on Stack Overflow. You could have posted this as a self-answered question. Although in this particular case this question is already asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987060/python-context-manager-that-measures-time and you should have answered there if your answer is / was unique.

Comment: Thanks! I clearly missed that checkbox. It seems I can't change it after posting. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: You can simply post an answer at any time. You don't have to enable the checkbox while posting the question.

Comment: Do you mean if I edit the question above to leave the only problem description in it and post the rest as an answer that makes the difference?